# Sitting vs Seated

Tags: word-usage, difference

> The person who is seated beside the host is a celebrity.
>
> The person who is sitting beside the host is a celebrity.

Difference between these two sentences and what is seated here an adjective or sth else.

Comment: The meaning is the same. EXCEPT, if you are seated, someone probably told you to sit there.

Comment: The person who is seated beside the host may not yet have arrived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most cases they are the same.

However, to be seated, may mean that the seating choice was decided in advance.  For example, in a formal situation, where people don't choose where they sit. For example:

> The competitors were seated in opposite corners, so that they couldn't see each other.

Also consider:

> The person who sits beside the host is a celebrity.

Sits/seated/sitting are verbs.
Sits is the third person singular form of "to sit", seated is the passive participle of "to seat", and sitting is the present participle of "to sit".